# Unable to find column with logical name: user_details_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(user_details) and its related supertables and secondary tables

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, orm, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create simple unidirectional mapping. I am using MappedSuperclass and @JoinColumn and there is probably a problem. Looks like  entity cannot find id field from super class.

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: user_details_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(user_details) and its related supertables and secondary tables
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:832) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:256) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1827) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1771) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1658) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

Super class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    private Long id;

}
```

Message entity (Joins id's of both sender and receiver)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity(name = "Message")
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message extends BaseEntity {
    private String title;
    private String details;
    private String message_container;
    private LocalDate dataOfSending;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sender_id", referencedColumnName = "user_details_id")
    private UserDetails sender;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id", referencedColumnName = "user_details_id")
    private UserDetails receiver;
}
```

User Details (should not know about messages)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "UserDetails")
@Table(name = "user_details")
public class UserDetails extends BaseEntity {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String motherName;
    private String fatherName;
    private String personalIdentityNum;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userDetails")
    private Address address;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userDetails")
    private Contact contact;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userDetails")
    private ProfileImage profileImage;

}
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you check my answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you just change this section in `Message` class

```
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sender_id", referencedColumnName = "user_details_id")
    private UserDetails sender;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id", referencedColumnName = "user_details_id")
    private UserDetails receiver;
```

to

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sender_id")
    private UserDetails sender;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id")
    private UserDetails receiver;
```

And in `UserDetails` add these code

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender")
private List<Message> senderMessage = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver")
private List<Message> receiverMessage = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Hi. Yes, it is one of possible solutions but I just thought if this can be achieved without mappings on UserDetails

Comment: Actually code works without specifying mapping on UserDetails side. But why? How it will find sender_id when there is no mapping in user details?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it will solve your problem, but I've just run in the same problem.
The trick is that in SpringBoot, you have to reference the *logical* id, NOT the db column name.

My case:

`PlayerEntity` has `playerId` that generates the column named `player_id`. This is a `@NaturalId`.

In the other entity, I wrote a `@ManyToOne`, which fails on setting `referencedColumnName = "player_id"`:

```
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: player_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(player) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

Since is says "logical name", I tried to change `player_id` to `playerId` (name of the field in `PlayerEntity`, and everything is working now:

```
    @ManyToOne
//    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id", referencedColumnName = "player_id") // fails
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id", referencedColumnName = "playerId") // works! What the...
    private PlayerEntity player;
```

This works, column with a correct FK is generated:

```
    constraint FK6aw598iko4dicfrfa6sj0mni1
        foreign key (player_id) references player (player_id)
```

This actually looks like a bug in Spring JPA or Hibernate. Database is MySQL 8.1.