# hibernate 4 "unable to find column" error

Tags: java, hibernate

```
package it.company.tserver.beans.indicatori.ondemand.persistent;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OrderBy;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "INDICATORS_OD")
@NamedQueries( { 
    @NamedQuery(name = "IndicatorOD.getAllIndicators", query = "SELECT o FROM IndicatorOD o ORDER BY o.description ASC"), 
    @NamedQuery(name = "IndicatorOD.getIndicatorsForType", query = "SELECT o FROM IndicatorOD o WHERE o.type = :type ORDER BY o.description ASC"), 
    @NamedQuery(name = "IndicatorOD.getReqTemplate", query = "SELECT o from IndicatorOD j LEFT JOIN j.reqTemplate o where j.codIndicator = :cod ORDER BY o.orderForm ASC"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "IndicatorOD.getRespTemplate", query = "SELECT o from IndicatorOD j LEFT JOIN j.respTemplate o where j.codIndicator = :cod ORDER BY o.orderForm ASC")
})

public class IndicatorOD implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1626218826909078278L;

    public enum IndicatorTypes {
        INDICATOROD, RENDOBBCALC
    }

    private String codIndicator;
    private String description;
    private IndicatorTypes type;

    private Set<IndicatorODTemplate> reqTemplate = new HashSet<IndicatorODTemplate>();
    private Set<IndicatorODRespTemplate> respTemplate = new HashSet<IndicatorODRespTemplate>();


    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE_IND")
    public String getCodIndicator() {
        return codIndicator;
    }
    public void setCodIndicator(String codIndicator) {
        this.codIndicator = codIndicator;
    }


    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


    @Column(name = "TYPE_IND")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public IndicatorTypes getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(IndicatorTypes type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("orderForm ASC")
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_IND", referencedColumnName = "CODE_IND")
    public Set<IndicatorODTemplate> getReqTemplate() {
        return reqTemplate;
    }


    public void setReqTemplate(Set<IndicatorODTemplate> template) {
        this.reqTemplate = template;
    }
    

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("orderForm ASC")
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_IND", referencedColumnName = "CODE_IND")
    public Set<IndicatorODRespTemplate> getRespTemplate() {
        return respTemplate;
    }


    public void setRespTemplate(Set<IndicatorODRespTemplate> respTemplate) {
        this.respTemplate = respTemplate;
    }
}
```

this deploys in jboss 4 with hibernate 3, in jboss 7.1 with hibernate 4 it gives an error :

org.hibernate.MappingException: **Unable to find column with logical name**: CODE_IND in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(INDICATORS_OD) and its related supertables and secondary tables

the joincolumn is on the same table, it's not a foreign key to another table, what could be the problem ?

the table in oracle is :

```
  CREATE TABLE "TSERVER"."INDICATORS_OD" 
   (    "CODE_IND" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "TYPE_IND" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_INDICATOR_OD" PRIMARY KEY ("CODE_IND")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TSDATA"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TSDATA" ;
```

19:24:32,328 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'TServer-4.1.0rc2.jar#oracledb'
19:24:32,336 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: oracledb
...]
19:24:32,362 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS014142: Started message driven bean 'IndicatorODMessagingBean' with 'hornetq-ra' resource adapter
19:24:33,257 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."TServer-4.1.0rc2.jar#oracledb": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."TServer-4.1.0rc2.jar#oracledb": Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152) [rt.jar:1.7.0_261]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622) [rt.jar:1.7.0_261]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.7.0_261]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: oracledb] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: **Unable to find column with logical name**: CODE_IND in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(INDICATORS_OD) and its related supertables and secondary tables
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:552)
at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1428)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindOneToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:749)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:677)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:626)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:66)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1586)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1359)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1724)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
... 9 more

Comment: Could you please write the hole error message or stack trace ?

Comment: upon reading this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370446/unable-to-find-column-with-logical-name-user-details-id-in-org-hibernate-mappin this seems to work because it deployed jar with AS 7  :  @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_IND", referencedColumnName = "codIndicator")

Comment: would any ide like eclipse detect this apparent problem and give some sort of marker warning ?